# How to profile disk io during testing to then create an FIO model?

Tags: performance

For linux (rhel/centos) systems, is there a way to collect/profile the disk io (iops, read throughput, write throughput, etc) of a system during active testing *with* the follow up ability to convert that to an FIO-type model/job file (flexible IO testing tool:  https://github.com/axboe/fio ) for repeatable testing of the disk io scenario directly?

This would be used to directly test disk io subsystems in a repeatable way without relying on re-running the original-tests used to create the model/profile (regardless of database server, application server, microservices, etc item used that generated the disk io), thanks!

(p.s. there is a lot of lip service to creating a benchmark, but I have yet to find a practical approach of how to actually do it using a system-under-test, please help!)

To clarify the request as it relates to creating a benchmark of a system-under-test, how would you capture the number of readers/writers to create a model of a system under test, file sizing to use for testing, how to verify block size, all those things needed to create a disk io benchmark (such as for FIO) based on observations of a system-under-test (most important - how to get and interpret those observations to create the model!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`blktrace`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blktrace) to trace the disk access pattern, and use these informations to create a similarly looking `fio` access pattern.

Comment: Good start, reviewing found https://brooker.co.za/blog/2013/07/14/io-performance.html talking about using blktrace and how to both replay using its own tools, and converting to FIO, testing it out now, as well as https://netofrombrazil.com/2015/01/05/capturing-and-replaying-block-traces-blktrace-btrecord-btreplay-and-fio/ to cross reference!